# 'types/values length mismatch',

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, javascript, error

Hey guys I had a problem with my return function

here's my smart contract :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract NewHello{ 

address owner;
address newOwner;
constructor()public{
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner (){
    if(msg.sender != owner){
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
    }
    else{
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}

struct user{
    string name;
    string surname;
    uint age;
}

 event infoChanged(
    string name,
    string surname,
    uint age
);

mapping(address => user) public users; // contains a user for every address


function setUser(string memory name,string memory surname,uint age) public payable{
    users[msg.sender] = user(name,surname,age);
    emit infoChanged(name,surname,age);
}

function setUserbyAdmin(address _address,string memory name,string memory surname,uint age) public  onlyOwner {
    users[_address] = user(name,surname,age);
    emit infoChanged(name,surname,age);
}

function getUser(address _address) public view returns(string memory name , string memory surname, uint age)  {

    return (users[_address].name,users[_address].surname,users[_address].age);        
}

}
```

and my web3.js code is here :

```
var getUserFunction = function(cb,_contractAddress = contractAddress, _jsonFile = JSONFile){
    var abi = JSONFile.abi;

    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,_contractAddress);

    contract.methods.getUser().call().then(function(data){
        cb(undefined,data);
    }).catch(function(err){
        cb(err,undefined)
    });

}


module.exports.getUser = getUserFunction;
```

and I call my function at orchestra.js. here's the code :

```
API.getUser(function(err,_data1,_data2,_data3){
    data1= _data1;
    data2=_data2;
    data3=_data3
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data1,data2,data3);
}, '0xDeDbB36387f42FEB764056d1D52391F0A6B15D04',//contractaddress
require('./build/contracts/NewHello.json'));
```

I see 2 errors on my terminal

**{ Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":0}, value={"types":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"values":[]}, version=4.0.29)**

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95748/discussion-on-question-by-furkan-demirel-types-values-length-mismatch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is my get function takes a parameter just modify this :

```
var getUserFunction = function(cb,_contractAddress = contractAddress, _jsonFile = JSONFile){
var abi = JSONFile.abi;

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,_contractAddress);

contract.methods.getUser('0xF15372bcF1FdD963Ea5514Dc96432Da8e795A8de').call().then(function(_data){
    cb(undefined,_data);
}).catch(function(err){
    cb(err,undefined)
});

}
```